# Node Express potential CORS issue with Ionic App using Restangular

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, restangular

I have an Ionic App that I am using restangular to communicate with a node express application.

Everything is working when I have the node express application configured to use http.

Ionic App side:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://11.22.33.44:3000');

// custom header
interceptors.serialNumber = function (element, operation, what, url, headers, query) {
  return {
    headers: angular.extend({
      'x-serialnumber': deviceStore.serialNumber
    }, headers)
  };
};

Restangular.one(‘Admin’).get()
 .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
   }, function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```

Node Express App side:

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.get('/Admin, function(req, res) {
    console.log(admin-get');
    res.send(200);
});
```

I was expecting I would need to handle a pre-flight request since the cors node module states:  “An example of a 'complex' CORS request is one that uses an HTTP verb other than GET/HEAD/POST (such as DELETE) or that uses custom headers.”  So I am not sure why this works?

I reconfigure the Ionic App and Node Express App to use a https address instead of a http:

Ionic App side:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://11.22.33.44:3000');

// custom header
interceptors.serialNumber = function (element, operation, what, url, headers, query) {
  return {
    headers: angular.extend({
      'x-serialnumber': deviceStore.serialNumber
    }, headers)
  };
};

Restangular.one(‘Admin’).get()
 .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
   }, function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```

Node Express App side:

```
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.get('/Admin, function(req, res) {
    console.log(admin-get');
    res.send(200);
});
```

when the Ionic App performs the GET request, I see in the Chrome debugger under “Network” an OPTIONS request that gets canceled (request’s status).  This tells me that I need to enable cors pre-flight on my Node Express App side (though why didn’t I see this error when the server was configured with http instead of https?).

So I tried the following on the Node Express App side per the express js cors module documentation:

```
app.options('Admin', cors()); // enable pre-flight request 
app.get('/Admin', cors(), function(req, res) {
    console.log('admin-get');
    res.send(200);
});
```

I see the same thing in the Chrome debugger under “Network” - a OPTIONS request that gets canceled (request’s status).  I also tried

```
app.options('*', cors());
```

with the same result.

I then removed the insertion of the custom header (x-serialnumber) on the Ionic App side.  It now works.

So why would the Node Express Application work when configured with a http address with out handling a pre-flight request I would expect due to the insertion of a custom header on the Ionic App side?

When the Node Express App is configured with a https address (as well as Ionic App side) why am I not handling the OPTIONS request?  Is the way I am configuring cors incorrect?  What am I missing?

I think it is a cors issue since I can eliminate the custom header on the Ionic App side when they are configured for a https address and it works.

What do I need to do to get this working?

**UPDATE**

I tried using Angular JS $http instead of Restangular.  I got the following result which works:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: theUrl
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: theUrl,
    headers: {
      'x-serialnumber' : deviceStore.serialNumber
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
  });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
});
```

I see in Chrome Network Debugger the first GET (**minus** the custom header) goes out and I get a good response (200), followed by the OPTIONS request where I also get a good response (200), followed by a good GET with the custom header in it (get good response back).

If I do **NOT** do this first GET request minus the custom header, the OPTIONS request aborts on the Angular JS Ionic App side with a status of -1.

**NOTE:  I can change out the initial $http request (minus custom header) for a Restangular request (minus custom header)**

Why is this initial GET minus the custom header needed (i.e. GET (minus custom header) | OPTIONS | GET (with custom header))?

What do I not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well what I needed to do was the following:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://example.com/DUMMY'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com',
    headers: {
      'x-serialnumber': deviceStore.serialNumber
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('FAILURE');
  });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log('FAILURE');
});
```

In essence, I needed to send a "**preliminary**" GET request with **NO** custom header. The GET request could be to anything on my node express server. After this "**preliminary**" GET request, I could perform the GET request with the custom header in it.

Specifically on the server side I see the following:

```
GET /DUMMY 200 10ms - 2b
OPTIONS / 204 1ms
GET / 200 13ms - 1.03kb
```

Without performing this "**preliminary**" get request, the OPTIONS request in my Ionic App would **abort - status code = -1** - usually means the request was aborted and would never leave Ionic App side.

I still do not understand why I need this "**preliminary**" GET request, but this works for me.